# attr_accessor prevent model fields to be saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am trying to adapt code to crop image coupled with some user javascript

Followed Railscast 184 as well as other tutorials but can't get it work. (Which is a good thing as it forces me to understand Ruby better)

Though my problem:

I am trying to save the cropping data into my database but a weird thing happen: the following bit `attr_accessor :x, :y, :width, :height` prevent these values being saved by the controller.

**controller update action**

```
if params[:profilepicupload] then
      newpic = @professionnel.build_profilepic
      newpic.image = params[:profilepicupload]
      newpic.save
    else
      ppic = @professionnel.profilepic
      ppic.x = params[:dataX]
      ppic.y = params[:dataY]
      ppic.height = params[:dataHeight]
      ppic.width = params[:dataWidth]
      ppic.save

    end
```

**Profilepic.rb model**

```
class Profilepic < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :professionnels

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { big: "1200x1200", medium: "400x400", small: "250x250"}, whiny: false, use_timestamp: false, processors: [:cropper]
  validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }, size: {less_than: 15.megabytes}
  attr_accessor :x, :y, :width, :height

end
```

When I remove the `attr_accessor` reference to the model file then the x,y,width and height values are saved into the model !

(In both cases the crop is not done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting your own `attr_accessor` methods you are overriding Rails logic to fetch those values from the database. I'm guessing you want those values to be saved in the database. If so, just add them as attributes to your model via migrations, and you should be all set.

Comment: Ok you mean I am trying to create getter and setter for values which are already in my database ? Which prevent those values to be saved at controller level ? (those x,y,width, height are already fields of profilepic model )

Comment: Right, if those are already fields of the model, then you shouldn't need to set getters or setters yourself - those methods should already exist. Or am i misunderstanding something here?

Comment: I understand now. The problem is that I am copy-pasting code that don't really fit my app architecture... And I am yet too beginner to adapt it myself.. then I bump in such silly things...

Comment: No worries. If your question is resolved, please mark it as solved :)